# permalinks constantly needs re-saving

Tags: permalinks, security, cache, nginx

I have my WP running on an Nginx environment, with Wordfence, WP Rocket, and Search&Filter plugins installed (along with some others). Permalinks are working just fine, except `/search` permalink which should be pointing (with S&F plugin) to `search.php`but returns error 404. saving permalinks settings fixes the problem, but after several hours the 404 comes back. I guess there is probably a scheduled job (cache? security) that is overriding S&F settings...

My server guy thinks it's S&F related, S&F support think it's a server config issue, and I'm stuck with a broken search system :)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit the Permalinks page, the permalinks rules are being flushed. It also forces WordPress to reload them. For this reason, you see the issue go away after saving permalink settings. But after some time, it comes back once again .

Try following these steps:

- Deactivate all the plugins. Then activate one by one. In this way,
  you can find the plugin that is causing the issue.
- Try using a different theme. If it fixes the issue, there must be a
  problem with the existing one.
- Check whether there is any issue in .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you. In my case I can't just turn off plugins or changing the theme, due to a lot of traffic in the site, and the fact it takes time for the issue to re-appear after I flush permalinks. about .htaccess, as far as I understand, Nginx has no such thing, it's working differently.